# redirect to www not working on Nginx server

Tags: nginx

I need to redirect my website from https://MY_SITE.com to https://www.MY_SITE.com.

I added another "server" instruction at the beginning of my .conf file. Here is the content of the file :

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name MY_SITE.com;
    return 301 https://www.MY_SITE.com$request_uri;
}


server {

    # Ipv4

    # IPv6
    # listen [::]:80;

    # SSL Ipv4 & v6
    # listen 443 default_server ssl;
    # listen [::]:443 ssl;

    # ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    # ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    # ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:RSA+3DES:AES128-SHA:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
    # ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    # Do not forget to create this file before with OpenSSL : "openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048"
    # ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

    # Your domain names here
    server_name www.MY_SITE.com MY_SITE.com 195.xxx.xxx.xxx;

    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    root /var/www/MY_SITE.com/public_html;


    # Your admin folder
    set $admin_dir /admin274fjp1q;

    # Gzip Settings, convert all types.
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;

    # Can be enhance to 5, but it can slow you server
    # gzip_comp_level    5;
    # gzip_min_length    256;

    gzip_types

        application/json
        application/ld+json
        application/manifest+json
        application/rss+xml
        application/vnd.geo+json
        application/vnd.ms-fontobject
        application/x-font-ttf
        application/x-web-app-manifest+json
        application/xhtml+xml
        application/xml
        font/opentype
        image/bmp
        image/svg+xml
        image/x-icon
        text/cache-manifest
        text/css
        text/plain
        text/vcard
        text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
        text/vtt
        text/x-component
        text/x-cross-domain-policy;
        # Supposed to be the case but we never know
        # text/html;

    # Global rewrite not depending on languages
    rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 last;
    rewrite "^/c/([0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/(.*)\.jpg$" /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/c/([_a-zA-Z-]+)/(.*)\.jpg$" /img/c/$1.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([a-z0-9]+)\-([a-z0-9]+)(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1-$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9]+)\-([0-9]+)/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1-$2.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
    rewrite "^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(\-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?/(\P{M}\p{M}*)*\.jpg$" /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;


    gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

    # Symfony controllers
    location ~ /(AdminDashboard|international|_profiler|module|product|feature|attribute|supplier|combination|specific-price|configure)/(.*)$ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args $admin_dir/index.php$is_args$args;
    }


    # Redirect needed to "hide" index.php
    location / {
        #try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$uri&$args;

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        # Old image system ?
        rewrite ^/([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2$3.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])([0-9])(-[_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)?(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9$10.jpg$
        rewrite ^/c/([0-9]+)(-[.*_a-zA-Z0-9-]*)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2$3.jpg last;
        rewrite ^/c/([a-zA-Z_-]+)(-[0-9]+)?/.+.jpg$ /img/c/$1$2.jpg last;

    }

    error_page 404 /index.php?controller=404;

    # Static assets delivery optimisations
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=31536000;

    # Cloudflare / Max CDN fix
    location ~* \.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|docx|zip|pptx|swf|txt|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|webp|flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav|mp4|m4v|ogg|webm|aac)$ {
      expires max;
      log_not_found off;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess .DS_Store .htpasswd etc
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }


    # PHP 7 FPM part
    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {

        fastcgi_index index.php;

        # Switch if needed
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        #include fcgi.conf;
        # Do not forget to update this part if needed
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        #fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_keep_conn on;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;

        # In case of long loading or 502 / 504 errors
        # fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
        # fastcgi_buffers 256 16k;
        # fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
        client_max_body_size 10M;

        # Temp file tweak
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 0;
        fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;

   }


   # Allow access to robots.txt but disable logging every access
   location = /robots.txt {
       allow all;
       log_not_found off;
       access_log off;
   }


   # Prevent injection of php files in directories a user can upload stuff
   location /upload {
       location ~ \.php$ { deny all; }
   }
   location /img {
       location ~ \.php$ {  deny all;}
   }

   # Ban access to source code directories
   location ~ ^/(app|bin|cache|classes|config|controllers|docs|localization|override|src|tests|tools|translations|travis-scripts|vendor)/ {
      deny all;
   }

   # Banned file types
   location ~ \.(htaccess|yml|log|twig|sass|git|tpl)$ {
       deny all;
   }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_SITE.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/MY_SITE.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}

server {
    if ($host = www.MY_SITE.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = MY_SITE.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name www.MY_SITE.com MY_SITE.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

The "Certbot" sections has been generated with Certbot ("certbot --nginx").

So with this configuration I get an error:

> "This page can't be reached"

I have look into other posts, and it seems to correspond to a loop but I can't find where, in the conf file, this loop is created.

Thanks for your help

P.S:

Here are my DNS records (few words in french but understandable I hope):

[DNS_RECORDS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3pWp.png)

Comment: Do you have a DNS record for the bare domain name (i.e. without the `www` subdomain)?

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks for your support, I added a screenshot of my DNS records at the end of my post

Comment: You should test your various websites and protocols using `curl -I` to identify if there is a redirection loop. Check the error log and access log.

Comment: @RichardSmith I tested `curl -I https://www.lemeilleurducbd.com` and it redirects to `Location: http://lemeilleurducbd.com`, which is strange because there are no such redirects in my conf file. I know my DNS records are a mess, it might be the issue

Comment: Use `nginx -T` to test the site and see the configuration as Nginx sees it. Check the access log to make sure that this response is coming from your server.

Comment: @RichardSmith I posted the result of `nginx -T` [here](https://justpaste.it/2wbo4), it might be that the server stops return a response before reaching my configuration file (in **sites-availables** folder), I am still investigating. Also, I checked my server access logs, and yes the response is coming from the server.

Comment: Looking at your `curl -I https://www.lemeilleurducbd.com` response headers, it indicates that it was generated by PHP. It suggests that your application is not configured correctly.

Comment: @RichardSmith I don't understand, it makes sense that Nginx use Php to return Html content as I also have the "PHP-FPM" extension installed...

Comment: Your PHP application (Prestashop?) appears to be generating the Location header in the 3xx response.

Comment: @RichardSmith it's so strange, I have activated SSL in the Prestashop admin, and it works, I don't see where the Location header is being changed to http

Comment: I just found the solution, I added www in the Shop domain and SSL domain values